# If $\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}$ is a basis, is $\{x_1+x_2,x_2+x_3,\cdots,x_n+x_1\}$ a basis too?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Let's say we have a vector space $V$ with a basis $\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}$ then is $\{x_1+x_2,x_2+x_3,\cdots,x_{n-1}+x_n,x_n+x_1\}$ a basis too?

**My Answer:**
For n=2 clearly this is false because of the following counter example:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}

If we apply the above to get the new set

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}

which is not linearly indepedent to form a basis.

But what about $n\geq3 ?$

I believe it should work by intuition that $v_1 = x_1+x_2$ can only be formed using $x_1$ and $x_2$ and so on hence any of the vectors cannot be formed using the others by any linear combination.

Comment: $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}\left((x_1+x_2)+(x_3+x_1)-(x_2+x_3)\right)$

Comment: This only proves that x1 is a linearly combination of the "v" vectors ... We need to prove that "v" vectors cannot be written in terms of other "v" vectors (so in that case it would either be proving x1+x2 is a linear combination of the other (x2+x3,x3+x4,....) or doing the same for xn+x1. Isn't that correct?

Comment: That shows that for the case of $n=3$ you have that $x_1$ can be written in terms of the $v$ vectors.  Similarly you can show that $x_2$ and $x_3$ can as well.  So, the span of the $v$ vectors contains the span of the $x$ vectors and so is a super space.  However, since the $v$ vectors are each written in terms of the $x$ it must also be a subspace, and hence the same space.  So, for the case of $n=3$ the $v$ vectors *do* form a basis.  Now... try exploring larger $n$ using a similar idea.  Keep in mind the possible differences between even $n$ and odd $n$.

Comment: Aha! So the way you have written $x_1 = \frac{1}{2} ((x_1+x_2) + (x_3+x_1)-(x_2+x_3))$ we can clearly do the same for $x_2 = \frac{1}{2} ((x_2+x_3 )+(x_1+x_2)-(x_3+x_1))$ now we can add those and we get a combination of $v_1= x_1+x_2$ in terms of the $v_1,v_2$ and $v_3$

Comment: Please refer to my updated answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a matter to show whether the $n \times n$ tranformation matrix
$$
\left( {\matrix{
   1 & 1 & 0 &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
   0 & 1 & 1 &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 1 &  \ddots  &  \vdots   \cr 
    \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  & 1  \cr 
   1 & 0 & 0 &  \cdots  & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
is invertible or not

By developing its determinant on the first column it is easy to show that it is $2$ if $n$ is odd and null if $n$ is even (for $3 \le n$).

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix

Answer (score 3):

Let there exist scalars $c_j$'s such that the following linear combination is equal to $0.$
$c_1(x_1+x_2)+c_2(x_2+x_3)+\ldots+c_{n-1}(x_{n-1}+x_n)+c_n(x_n+x_1)=0$

**Case 1:** $n$ is even:

Let $n=2m,\ m\in\Bbb N$.
\begin{aligned}&c_1(x_1+x_2)+c_2(x_2+x_3)+\ldots+c_{2m-1}(x_{2m-1}+x_{2m})+c_{2m}(x_{2m}+x_1)=0\\\implies& (c_1+c_{2m})x_1+(c_1+c_2)x_2+(c_2+c_3)x_3+\ldots+(c_{2m-2}+c_{2m-1})x_{2m-1}+(c_{2m-1}+c_{2m})x_{2m}=0\end{aligned}

Hence, 
$c_i+c_{i+1}=0, i=1,2,\ldots,2m-1$ and $c_{2m}+c_1=0\tag 1$ 
Now, note that \begin{aligned}c_{2i+1}&=c_1, i=1,2,\ldots,m-1&\\&&\text{and}&\\c_2&=c_{2i},i=2,3,\ldots,m.&\end{aligned}
By $(1)$, $c_1+c_{2m}= c_1+c_2=0.$

Take $c_1= 2$, say, then,clearly $c_2=-2, c_3=2$ etc. 
Hence, we don't necessarily have $c_i=0\ \forall i=1,2,3,\ldots,n$.

Thus, $x_1+x_2,x_2+x_3,\ldots,x_n+x_1$ are not linearly independent and thus can't be basis.

**Case 2:** $n$ is odd:

Let $n=2k+1, k\in\Bbb N$. 
Proceed as in case $(1)$ above to get a system of linear equations similar to $(1)$ 
$c_i+c_{i+1}=0,i=1,2,\ldots,2k$ and $c_{2k+1}+c_1=0\tag{2}$
Again, note that \begin{aligned}c_{2i+1}&=c_1, i=1,2,\ldots,k&\\&&\text{and}\\c_2&=c_{2i},i=2,3,\ldots,k.&\end{aligned}

By $(2)$, \begin{aligned}c_1+c_{2k+1}= c_1+c_1&=0\\\implies c_1&=0=c_3=\ldots=c_{2k+1}\end{aligned}

and hence, again by $(2), c_2=c_4=\ldots=0$. Thus, in this case, $x_1+x_2,x_2+x_3,\ldots,x_n+x_1$ are linearly independent and thus form a basis.

Comment: Downvoter: Please explain.

Comment: Consider the parity of $n$

Comment: In more words... is it possible for $c_1$ to simultaneously equal $2$ *and* $-2$?  If $n$ were odd, is it possible to do as you suggest?

Comment: @JMoravitz: I see it now. Thanks a lot for very constructive response. For odd $n$, there will be trouble.

Comment: To emphasize, this is a good half of the solution and once "*etc*" in your proof is changed to something more formal proves that for even $n$ they will indeed be linearly dependent.  To complete the proof for odd $n$, consider my hint in the comments under the question.

Comment: @JMoravitz can we use the proof presented by Koro but at the same time distinguish between even and odd n ? So starting with the assumption that c1,c2 and c3 (for n=3) are not 0 , doing the resorting of the constants we get equations ... c1 = -c3 , c2 = -c1 and c3= -c2 which is only possible is c's are 0 and for even we can use Koro's part.

Comment: Yes, so long as you can formalize each step.  (*hint for the $n=3$ case, what you've written implies that $c_1=-c_3$ as well as $c_1=-c_2 = -(-c_3)$ so $c_3=-c_3$, now generalize to larger $n$*)

Comment: @JMoravitz: I have updated my answer. Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

To prove your claim where $n\geq 3$ is odd you have to show two properties:

1.) Let be $v\in V$ then $v$ must be contained in the linear span of $\{ x_1+x_2, x_2+x_3+, ..., x_n+x_1\}$. For sake of simplicity we define: $\{ x_1+x_2, x_2+x_3+, ..., x_n+x_1\}:=\{y_1, y_2, ...,y_n\}$.

2.) The vectors $y_1, y_2, ...,y_n$ must be linearly independent.

---

Regarding 1.):

If $v\in V$ then there exists a linear combination of $v$ regarding the initial basis $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$, namely $v=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_ix_i$. Then $v\in\{ y_1,y_2,..., y_n\}$ iff there exists a linear combination $v=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_i y_i$. If we simply set $b_j:= \sum\limits_{i=1}^j a_i (-1)^{j-i}+(-1)^j a_n$ where $j\in\{1,2,...,n\}$, then via induction it holds $v=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_i y_i=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_ix_i$. So the arbitrarily chosen vector $v$ is element of the span of $\{y_1, y_2, ...,y_n\}$.

Regarding 2.):

Let be $c_1,c_2,..., c_n$ some coefficients from the associated field, then we know that:

the vectors $y_1, y_2, ...,y_n$ are linearly independent iff $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n c_iy_i=0 \Rightarrow c_1=c_2=...=c_n=0$.

Let's assume $y_1, y_2, ...,y_n$ were not linearly independent then there must be at least one $i\in\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ with $c_i\neq 0$ such that:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n c_iy_i= 0$. By applying the inital assumption this leads to $0=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n c_iy_i= (c_1+c_n)x_1+ (c_1+c_2)x_2+ (c_2+c_3)x_3+ ...+c_n x_n$.

This is a contradiction because $x_1, x_2, ...x_n$ are linearly independent. So the vectors $y_1, y_2,...y_n$ must be linearly independent. Hence, the vectors $\{y_1, y_2, ...,y_n\}$ are another basis of $V$.

Answer (score 1):

When $n$ is even, $(x_1+x_2)-(x_2+x_3)+(x_3+x_4)-\cdots+(x_{n-1}+x_n)-(x_n+x_1)=0$. Hence $B=\{x_1+x_2,\ x_2+x_3,\,\ldots,\,x_{n-1}+x_n,\ x_n+x_1\}$ is linearly *dependent* and it cannot be a basis.

When $n\ge3$ is odd, $(x_1+x_2)-(x_2+x_3)+\cdots-(x_{n-1}+x_n)+(x_n+x_1)=2x_1$ and the similar holds for other $x_i$s. Hence $B$ spans $V$ and it is a basis because $|B|=n=\dim V$.